# Backslash inside and outside of regex, $1 vs \1

Tags: regex, perl

I am seeing some strange behavior with grouping in Perl.

Below is a file snippet I have:

```
nmos MNANT2(sam_1_,sam_1_,sam_1_);  
nmos MNANT1(sam[0],sam[0],sam[0]);  
nmos MNANT3(ovstb,ovstb,ovstb);
nmos M3(net14, VSS, in);
```

Basically I am trying to match those lines, where all the 3 fields inside braces are same.

Was trying it out with below one liners:

```
perl -nle 'm/(.+?\((.+?),$2,$2\).+)/ && print $1' new
```

It doesn't work, but the below guy works fine:

```
perl -nle 'm/(.+?\((.+?),\2,\2\).+)/ && print $1' new
```

So, my doubt is why $2 didn't work and \2 works well here?
Shouldn't we be using "$" for back references, as I have used $1 towards the end?

And, Okay, if "\" works fine everywhere, I just tried putting \1 also, instead of $1 like below:

```
perl -nle 'm/(.+?\((.+?),\2,\2\).+)/ && print \1' new
```

It returns below error:

```
SCALAR(0x1a49678)
SCALAR(0x1a49678)
SCALAR(0x1a49678)
```

What am I missing fundamentally here? Looking forward from the experts.

Comment: Have you read the [section on back references in perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Backreferences)? "*Although $1 and \g1 represent the same thing, care should be taken to use matched variables $1 , $2 ,... only outside a regexp and backreferences \g1 , \g2 ,... only inside a regexp; not doing so may lead to surprising and unsatisfactory results.*". See also [\1 vs $1 in perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-%5c1-Instead-of-%241)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think the regex patterns and Perl code are the same language. `a+b` in a regex pattern isn't addition, and `\2` outside a regex isn't an instruction to match the second capture.

---

`perl -nle 'm/(.+?\((.+?),$2,$2\).+)/ && print $1' new` doesn't work because `$2` is interpolated into the pattern before the pattern is even compiled.

`perl -nle 'm/(.+?\((.+?),\2,\2\).+)/ && print $1' new` works because the regex atom `\2` means "match what the second capture captured."

`perl -nle 'm/(.+?\((.+?),\2,\2\).+)/ && print \1' new` doesn't work because `\` is Perl's reference-taking operator.

Comment: Thanks. I understand "\"  should be used for back referencing within regex and $ to be used for getting string after executing regex.

Answer (score 1):

The `m//` and `print` commands are separate commands joined by an `&&`.

Within a regex `\2` is a backreference to the second capture, which will be assigned to the `$2` variable after the regex has finished matching. Outside the regex `\2` is meaningless; only `$2` is a variable that can be accessed. See here for more info: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Backreferences

When reading that link, note that after Perl 5.10 `\2` is still recognized but `\g2` is encouraged. This is because `\11` is ambiguous.